# Pass variable to Json Encoder in Go

Tags: go

I have a token that contains the generated json web token. I was trying to pass it to a json encoder to be passed to the client.

```
  token := "generatedtoken"
  json.NewEncoder(res).Encode(`{ success: true, message: "Successfully logged in." }`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do:

```
token := "sometoken"
response := map[string] interface{} {
    "success":true,
    "message": "Successfully logged in.", 
    "token": token}
json.NewEncoder(res).Encode(&response)
```

or you can wrap the response in a struct.